# "God of Heaven" in the book of Daniel

Tags: daniel, names-of-god, terminology

I noticed that "the God of heaven" is a common title used for God in the book of Daniel. Is this name used anywhere else in the Scriptures? Why is it used so much in the book of Daniel? (Perhaps for contrast with the pagan gods?) What all does the phrase denote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to F.F. Bruce's *Israel and the Nations* (p 108):

> "the God of Heaven" is a title by which Yahweh is commonly designated under the Persian regime

The phrase is not just used in Daniel, but also used in Ezra 7:12 where Ezra is designated "scribe of the law of the God of heaven" in Artaxerxe's letter to Ezra.

It is used throughout the book of Daniel, because of the title's use in official court documents, and Daniel's living in the royal palace.

Comment: In manuscript, Ezra 7:12, Aram. "Elaha Shamaya".

Comment: In manuscript, Ezra 7:*12*, Aramaic "Elaha Shamaya". See Daniel 2:19 same Aramaic. See Genesis 24:3 for first use in Hebrew, preceded by the tetragrammaton, followed by "and God of the earth". See Nehemiah 1:4 (Heb.).

Comment: Thanks Eli for noticing my incorrect reference - I have just corrected it :-)